# How Chk two checkboxes at a time using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two jQuery modal popups with two checkboxes. How to check or uncheck both the check-boxes at the same time?

For example: modal popup1 has chkbox no1 and Modal-popup2 with chkbox no2.
I want when the chkbox no1 is checked the chkbox no2 should also be checked and vise-versa.

I have used same class and onclick function for both the chkboxes.

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxno1" onClick="clcikchkbox(this)" chartshowvalue="#dialog-chart-setting" class="viz_chart-show_value" value=1/>
 <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxno2" onClick="clcikchkbox(this)" chartshowvalue="#dialog-chart-setting" class="viz_chart-show_value" value=1/>

 function clcikchkbox(elem){
 var addchartShowvalue = $(elem).attr('chartshowvalue');
    if ($(elem).is(':checked')) {
        Dataviz.setting.chart[0].showvalue = 1;
    } else {
        Dataviz.setting.chart[0].showvalue = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `$('.viz_chart-show_value').prop('checked', $(elem).is(':checked'));` - in my deleted comment I made a typo, this should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a typo in my original comment to your post, this should work (I commented out lines with `Dataviz` because it's undefined in this snippet.)

```js
 function clcikchkbox(elem){
 var addchartShowvalue = $(elem).attr('chartshowvalue');
    if ($(elem).is(':checked')) {
        //Dataviz.setting.chart[0].showvalue = 1;
    } else {
        //Dataviz.setting.chart[0].showvalue = 0;
    }
    $('.viz_chart-show_value').prop('checked', $(elem).is(':checked'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxno1" onClick="clcikchkbox(this)" chartshowvalue="#dialog-chart-setting" class="viz_chart-show_value" value=1/>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxno2" onClick="clcikchkbox(this)" chartshowvalue="#dialog-chart-setting" class="viz_chart-show_value" value=1/>
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect, thank you so much @Walk.I was just missing the condition to chk both the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

if I correctly understand, you want to check both checkboxes at the same time. use something like this :

```js
 function clcikchkbox(){
 var ch1=$('#checkboxno1').is(':checked'); //return true or false
 var ch2=$('#checkboxno2').is(':checked'); //return true or false
 
    if (ch1 && ch2) { //if both checkboxs were checked
        Dataviz.setting.chart[0].showvalue = 1;
    } else {
        Dataviz.setting.chart[0].showvalue = 0;
    }
}
```